# Remove from list in python 3

Tags: python, list

I have a list that I have scraped from a website. I want to remove the links that are anchors for the various pages of the site, for example '/about/'. There are a number of them. Rather than make different loops that remove from the list, is there a way that I can build a code that looks at the text and if "http" (not just https like the data below has because what if the "s" is not there) is in the text then it would add it to the list? My list data is this:

```
['mailto:info@yourdomain.com', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/about/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/services/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/educational-courses/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/articles-and-downloads/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/videos/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/calculators/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/news/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/contact/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/about/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/services/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/educational-courses/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/articles-and-downloads/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/videos/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/calculators/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/news/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/contact/', '/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-back-to-school-season/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-back-to-school-season/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-things-to-know-about-getting-life-insurance-for-your-child/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-things-to-know-about-getting-life-insurance-for-your-child/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-signs-you-need-to-up-your-life-insurance-coverage/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-signs-you-need-to-up-your-life-insurance-coverage/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-summer-travel/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-summer-travel/', 'mailto:Info@yourdomain.com', '/about/', '/events/', '/news/', '/contact/', 'https://youtechassociates.com/', '/privacy-policy', '/terms-of-use', '/disclosure/']
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What code have you tried and what were the issues you faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
mlist = your-list-as-specified-above

newlist = []
for m in mlist:
    if m.startswith('http'):
        newlist.append(m)
```

Comment: this seems to be the easiest way to get this done. Can it check if it starts with 'http' or 'mailto'?  edit: I figured that out by just adding "or" and check through it again.

Comment: `for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
        if anchor['href'].startswith('http') or anchor['href'].startswith('mail'):
            output.append(anchor['href'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list-comprehension with a regex to filter out links that do not contain the protocol:

```
[link for link in links if re.match('https?\:\/\/', link)]
```

giving:

```
['https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/about/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/services/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/educational-courses/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/articles-and-downloads/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/videos/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/calculators/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/news/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/contact/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/about/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/services/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/educational-courses/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/articles-and-downloads/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/videos/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/calculators/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/news/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/contact/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-back-to-school-season/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-back-to-school-season/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-things-to-know-about-getting-life-insurance-for-your-child/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-things-to-know-about-getting-life-insurance-for-your-child/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-signs-you-need-to-up-your-life-insurance-coverage/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-signs-you-need-to-up-your-life-insurance-coverage/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-summer-travel/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-summer-travel/', 'https://youtechassociates.com/']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *filter* to get this result

```
a = ['mailto:info@yourdomain.com', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/about/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/services/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/educational-courses/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/articles-and-downloads/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/videos/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/calculators/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/news/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/contact/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/about/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/services/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/educational-courses/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/articles-and-downloads/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/videos/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/calculators/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/news/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/contact/', '/events/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-back-to-school-season/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-back-to-school-season/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-things-to-know-about-getting-life-insurance-for-your-child/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-things-to-know-about-getting-life-insurance-for-your-child/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-signs-you-need-to-up-your-life-insurance-coverage/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/5-signs-you-need-to-up-your-life-insurance-coverage/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-summer-travel/', 'https://www.demodms.com/annuity/tips-for-summer-travel/', 'mailto:Info@yourdomain.com', '/about/', '/events/', '/news/', '/contact/', 'https://youtechassociates.com/', '/privacy-policy', '/terms-of-use', '/disclosure/']

b = filter(lambda x: 'http' not in  x, a)
print(list(b))
```

**Output:**

> ['mailto:info@yourdomain.com', '/events/', 'mailto:Info@yourdomain.com', '/about/', '/events/', '/news/', '/contact/', '/privacy-policy', '/terms-of-use', '/disclosure/']

Answer (score 0):

I would go with list comprehension and `startswith()`:

```
full_links = [link for link in links if link.startswith('http://') or link.startswith('https://')]
```

I think this is clearer than regex when you have such a simple task. Also, IMO you should ask for `http://` and `https://` explicitly, because only using `http` might give you false positives if you meet relative links like `http_stuff/foo.html`.